# ForceDarkAllowed for specific Compose component or how to fix weird text color in dark mode on some Xiaomi phones?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, xiaomi, miui, android-darkmode

I have trouble with text color in dark mode on some Xiaomi devices with android 10.
The component is clickable `Box` with text, if item selected - the text color is back and box is white and vise versa. The colors specified directly. Also I use custom color scheme and theme for my app (not a material theme).

Note: I have 5 Xiaomi devices with android 10+ and only one of them have issue with text color in the selected item. On this device the color is white (instead of black) on light background

*I can't provide the code of this component*

**So I have few questions:**

- how to fix it without disabling `ForceDarkAllowed` for whole app theme and without creating additional themes? (I can't to do this cause this is very global solution)
- can I set `ForceDarkAllowed` only for specific Compose component (not a android view)?
- can I fix it in some other way?
- if no options except of disabling `ForceDarkAllowed`, I want to know what the default value of `ForceDarkAllowed` for other, not Xiaomi, devices and which troubles I can encounter cause of this global theme value changing?

P.S. I almost fixed this issue by placing my component inside a `Surface` with `shadowElevation`, but this has effect only before user interactions with this component, after click on the other component like this - text is white again

Comment: @AyushiKhandelwal sadly, but now. I managed to fix problem with specific component only with using global ForceDarkAllowed  theme parameter